# Reactive Shield Spells in DFRPG

Tags: spells, magic, dresden-files, fate

So after reading the Paranet Papers, my group is now attempting to sort out the new rules concerning reactive shield spells. The main issue we're having is what to do about rote spells. PP doesn't mention them at all in this section, instead describing reactive shielding as "...a sudden burst of your will against an attack." It also says that it can't have any duration modifier added.
So here are my questions:

1. Does the no duration thing mean that you just can't add turns to it, or that it literally has no duration, as in it only lasts for the attack in question, rather than for the standard "until the end of your next turn"?
2. If it only lasts for the attack, does that cover all attacks that you're targeted by that turn, or just the one?
3. Can rotes be used reactively?
4. If they can, and the duration of a reactive shield is only for the attack rather than the standard rules, are rotes subject to this limitation?

Any help on this is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The key line here is:

" If you want to do a shield spell as a defense instead of a block, you’re more than welcome  to, but remember that you have to pay all the associated costs for the spell and make a Discipline roll just like with any other spell."

1. This is not a block, it's a defense roll. That means that the spell does not last beyond the attack.
2. Similar to the above answer. As a defense roll it is only against that specific attack. You would have to do it multiple times to stop multiple attacks.
3. Since one of the big benefits of a rote spell is bypassing the Discipline roll and the rule makes specific reference to casting a spell like normal, I would say yes.
4. I think the key to this one is the phrase in the next line that "you can’t modify a defense spell in any way". So if your rote spell would normally have a duration then you can't use that. Basically you would need a rote spell like Spirit Shield that is normally a 4 shift block that you can call up.